# C# Specifying orderby in extension method

Tags: c#, linq

How to specify descending in extension method

```
var qry=from p in context.Persons 
                   orderby p.salary descending select p;
```

extension method

```
var qry=context.Persons.OrderBy(c=>c.salary);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
var qry=context.Persons.OrderByDescending(c=>c.salary);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var qry=context.Persons.OrderByDescending(c=>c.salary);
```